# Stuck on Nova (iPhone app) - Fire Fight level

Tags: ios, nova

I am stuck on the Fire Fight level.  I cannot pass the room where the ship or roof collapsed.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Gaming.Stackexchange! Your question is very vague right now -- is the name of the game "Nova"? You could probably stand to rework your question title and question itself with more thorough grammar. It isn't quite clear what you're asking for -- a walkthrough? Step-by-step? A hint?

Comment: @Raven - Nova: Near Orbit Vanguard Alliance is the name of the game. It is a first-person shooter for iOS.

Comment: @Rodney - I have attempted to clarify your question, however, it would be helpful if you could explain what exactly is giving you difficulty. Is it a puzzle? A difficult fight? Please edit your question to give us a little more information.